# Cucumber : Retrieve the name of the runner or his class name

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

i have the below two runners :

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber_parallel_BR00.json", "junit:target/cucumber_parallel-junit-report-BR00.xml",
        "rerun:target/failed_scenarios/failed_parallel_once_BR00.txt", "timeline:target/timeline_BR00"},
        features = {"classpath:features/parallel/BR00"},
        tags = "(@UI or @API) and (not @Ignored)",
        glue = {"com.intrasoft.ermis.e2e.stepdefs"},
        monochrome = true)

public class E2ECucumberParallelRunner_BR00 extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
```

and

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber_parallel_BR01.json", "junit:target/cucumber_parallel-junit-report-BR01.xml",
        "rerun:target/failed_scenarios/failed_parallel_once_BR01.txt", "timeline:target/timeline_BR01"},
        features = {"classpath:features/parallel/BR01"},
        tags = "(@UI or @API) and (not @Ignored)",
        glue = {"com.intrasoft.ermis.e2e.stepdefs"},
        monochrome = true)

public class E2ECucumberParallelRunner_BR01 extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
```

during the execution of @BeforeAll i would like to retrieve the name of the runner or the name of the class because based on the runner i would like to set same data in the env before all scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach with two steps:

1. Create a static holder of current runner identifier like

```java
public class RunnerInfo {

  private static name;

  public static setName(String value){
    if(name == null){
      name = value;
    }else{
      throw new IllegalStateException("Runner name has been alread identified");
    }
  }

  public static String getName(){
    return name;
  }

}
```

2. Since you are using TestNg as test runner you can simply add constructor to your runner that would set up any name you want.

```java
public class Runner1 extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

  public Runner1(){
    RunnerInfo.setName("My runner");
  }

}
```

and for another one

```java
public class Runner2 extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

  public Runner2(){
    RunnerInfo.setName("My another runner");
  }

}
```

Now let's retrieve the name from the hook:

```java
public class MyHook {

  @BeforeAll
  public static void globalSetUp(){
    System.out.println(RunnerInfo.getName());
  }

}
```